# How do i configure universal USB modems (e.g. iBall 3.5G Connect)

Tags: 11.10, wireless, modem, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

There is no user guide with this USB modem for linux installation and it is not detected automatically in Ubuntu 11.10. Help.